# get screenshots from SurfaceComposerClient

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

Is it possible to use SurfaceComposerClient to get screenshots, the way MediaCodec does with createInputSurface().

I cant use MediaCodec for that because I need raw video and not encoded data.

since 4.3 it seems that ScreenshotClient  cant do multiple screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming you're running as `shell` or `root`, and you don't mind using non-public native APIs (i.e. you don't care if your app breaks every time a new version of the OS rolls out).

The canonical example is [screenrecord](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-screen-recording), introduced in Android 4.4.  It creates a virtual display and directs the output to a `Surface`.  For normal operation a `MediaCodec` input surface receives the output.  For the "bugreport" mode introduced in [screenrecord v1.1](http://www.bigflake.com/screenrecord/), the output goes to a `GLConsumer` (roughly equivalent to a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html)), which is rendered to a `Surface` with overlaid text.

Comment: in screenrecord 1.1 Overlay, What do I need to do to get the image raw bytes from the outputSurface (IGraphicBufferProducer) ?

Comment: In `setup_l()`, Overlay creates an EGL window surface for the IGraphicBufferProducer.  That feeds into the video encoder.  If you instead create a pbuffer surface, you can then use `glReadPixels()` to extract the data after the texture blit in `processFrame_l()`.

Comment: I have finally got it to work, but it slows the device terribly, unlike MediaCodec that doesn't slow at all ( and it also does encoding what should of been slower than just grab raw data, no ?  ).
Any way I can speed it up ?

Comment: Something I learned recently is that, if EGL isn't configured with an alpha plane, `glReadPixels(GL_RGBA)` can take an absurdly long time on certain devices (177ms vs. 6ms).  In `eglSetupContext()` (or wherever you're configuring EGL for your pbuffer), below `EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,` add `EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,` and see if that helps.

Comment: EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8, didnt help
would you mind taking a look at my code, maybe I am doing glReadPixels() in the wong place.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36894441/EglWindow.cpp
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36894441/Overlay.cpp

Comment: In `createWindow()`, use `mWidth` and `mHeight` in the `pbufferAttribs` so it doesn't have to scale (I suspect you're scaling the display resolution to 1280x800, then scaling it back to display res when extracting... unless you're on a device with a 1280x800 display).  Before we go too far down this road, you should bracket the `glReadPixels()` call with `systemTime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` calls to see just how long each invocation is taking... maybe the performance problem is elsewhere.  (Maybe install https://github.com/google/grafika and run the "glReadPixels speed test"?)

Comment: I am using a display of 1280x800 - nexus 7 ( hard coded just for tests ) , I added a time test around glReadPixels and got avg of 220 ms per call. 
perhaps I should be using a Pixel Buffer Object ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45308/discussion-between-jacob-and-fadden)

Comment: Got my Nexus 7 (2012) updated.  Grafika reports ~200ms for a 1280x720 frame, consistent with your results.  Ugh.

Comment: I am trying EGL_KHR_image_base  with no success, can you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151259/replacing-glreadpixels-with-egl-khr-image-base-for-faster-pixel-copy

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in Android 4.3 (see issues [59649](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59649) or [60638](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60638) on the Android Open Source Project Issue Tracker) which means ScreenshotClient can't be used to take more than one screenshot.